# Share GraphQL/Apollo local and retrieved data in unrelated React components (using Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Yes, there are other similar posted questions that I've been bashing my head over and just can't seem to arrive at a consistent and clear answer. Perhaps someone can provide a solid answer for Stack Overflow and me. I think this is fundamental and should be made more clear in the docs. I'm looking to move from a centralized data store strategy and trying to grasp the concepts here. While Apollo does a lot of neat stuff, it seems less comprehensive than a central store regarding sharing data with the tree.

***If I query data in one component how do I access that data in an unrelated component?***

Is this the right way to do it?

```
const queries = {
    GET_BOOKS: gql`
        {
            AllBooks: book {
                id
                title
            }
        }
    `
}

const BookList = () => { 

    const allBooks = useQuery(queries.GET_BOOKS);

    return (
        <>
            {
                !allBooks.loading 
                && allBooks.diata 
                && allBooks.data.map((book, n) => <Book key={n} data={book} />)
            }
        </>
    );
};

const BookCounter = () => {

    const allBooks = useQuery(queries.GET_BOOKS);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                !allBooks.loading 
                && allBooks.data 
                && allBooks.data.length
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you want to share data at an arbitrary depth in your component tree, I think using React Context seems to be a useful approach. Personally I applied it successfully in some projects in conjunction with Apollo / GraphQL. There also is a hook useContext.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Doesn't this fly in the face of a "single source of truth"? I guess, more directly, is Apollo a state manager or not? Isn't the reason that we pass `ApolloProvider` to the top-level App component so this stuff is available throughout the tree?

Comment: Yes, the client itself can be used for state management as well. However if you need the results from a single query you can pass it down as well. In my case there was additional processing. The queries itself are actually cached, so, if you use the useQuery hook again woth the same parameters, its just a lookup.

Comment: So, assuming the data consumed is the same in all locations, you treat each consuming component as a first-class requester of data and let Apollo determine when the server request needs to be made?

Comment: Yes, at least that's what I would do :). Apollo caches all queries, so there is (almost) no extra cost.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Rob! With your nudges and this example app I think I'm starting to get it. https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial/tree/master/final/client/src